# VB.Net Online Time

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that returns the online date and time but for some reason the minutes are not working. When I add a value to the minutes it always stays the same and won't move forward.

```
 Public Function OnlineTimeNow() As DateTime

        '　--- create instance of UDP
        Dim objSck As System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
        Dim ipAny As System.Net.IPEndPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 0)
        objSck = New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(ipAny)
        ' --- send UDP
        Dim sdat As Byte() = New Byte(47) {}
        sdat(0) = &HB
        objSck.Send(sdat, sdat.GetLength(0), "time.windows.com", 123)
        ' --- receive UDP
        Dim rdat As Byte() = objSck.Receive(ipAny)
        ' elapsed time (date and time) from 1900/01/01 --- 
        Dim elapsedTotalSec As Long ' elapsed seconds from 1900/01/01 --- 
        Dim Days As Long    ' days --- 日
        Dim HH As Long    ' hours --- 時
        Dim MM As Long    ' minutes --- 分
        Dim SS As Long    ' seconds --- 秒
        ' --- elapsed seconds from 1900/01/01 --- 
        elapsedTotalSec = CLng(
              rdat(40) * Math.Pow(2, (8 * 3)) +
              rdat(41) * Math.Pow(2, (8 * 2)) +
              rdat(42) * Math.Pow(2, (8 * 1)) +
              rdat(43))
        ' ---
        Days = elapsedTotalSec \ (24 * 60 * 60)   ' days 
        SS = elapsedTotalSec Mod (24 * 60 * 60) ' mod seconds 
        HH = SS \ (60 * 60)
        SS = SS Mod (60 * 60)
        MM = MM \ (60 * 60)
        SS = SS Mod 60
        ' --- convert to DateTime type 
        'Dim dtTime As DateTime = "1900/01/01"
        Dim dtTime As DateTime
        'dtTime = dtTime.AddDays(Days)
        dtTime = dtTime.AddHours(HH)
        dtTime = dtTime.AddMinutes(MM)
        dtTime = dtTime.AddSeconds(SS)
        ' --- change Greenwich Mean Time to local time (my sample is Japanese Time) 
        dtTime = dtTime.AddHours(8) ' <<-- *** please modify (n) according to your location ***
        ' ---
        Return dtTime

    End Function
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `MM` except this `MM = MM \ (60 * 60)`, using only itself.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the GTM Time ?

Comment: yes, i 've been searching everywhere with no luck on how to make this work :( maybe you can help me please

Comment: [World Time API Org](https://worldtimeapi.org/) => [Manila current time](https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Manila.txt) (Plain Text), [Manila current time](https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Manila) (JSON)

Comment: For example: `dim client as WebClient = New WebClient() dim manilaDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(client.DownloadString("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Manila.txt").Split(ChrW(10)).Skip(2).First().Substring(10))`

Comment: MM = SS \ 60, symmetry needs to be preserved.

Comment: Thanks Guys <3 <3
i will try yours @Jimi - thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just To Post a Simple Method for the Next User "Online Date and Time VB.NET"

```
Private Sub OnlineDateAndTime()

        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()

        'Download The TextFile From Web.
        'Refer To "https://worldtimeapi.org/" about the link below
        Dim DateAndTimeFromWeb = DateTimeOffset.Parse(client.DownloadString("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Manila.txt").Split(ChrW(10)).Skip(2).First().Substring(10))


        Dim TimeNow As DateTime
        Dim DateNow As DateTime


        'Get Only Time
        TimeNow = DateAndTimeFromWeb.ToString
        TimeNow = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")

        'Get Only Date
        DateNow = DateAndTimeFromWeb.ToString
        DateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

        'Show Results in Textbox or Label or Any
        TextBox1.Text = DateNow
        TextBox2.Text = TimeNow

    End Sub
```

Credits to @Jimi - Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the GTM time, you can do it simply with :

```
Dim dtTime As DateTime
dtTime = DateTime.UtcNow
```

This is an exemple on how to convert Utc time to another time zone :

```
 Sub Main()

        Dim DT As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow    
        Dim DTSEAsia As DateTime
        Dim Tz As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SE Asia Standard Time")

        DTSEAsia = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DT, Tz)

    End Sub
```

And this are the value possible for a `TimeZoneInfo`

```
Dateline Standard Time
UTC-11
Samoa tandard Time
Hawaiian Standard Time
Alaskan Standard Time
Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)
Pacific Standard Time
US Mountain Standard Time
Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)
Mountain Standard Time
Central America Standard Time
Central Standard Time
Central Standard Time (Mexico)
Canada Central Standard Time
SA Pacific Standard Time
Eastern Standard Time
US Eastern Standard Time
Venezuela Standard Time
Paraguay Standard Time
Atlantic Standard Time
Central Brazilian Standard Time
SA Western Standard Time
Pacific SA Standard Time
Newfoundland Standard Time
E.South America Standard Time
Argentina Standard Time
SA Eastern Standard Time
Greenland Standard Time
Montevideo Standard Time
UTC-2
Mid-Atlantic Standard Time
Azores Standard Time
Cape Verde Standard Time
Morocco Standard Time
UTC
GMT Standard Time
Greenwich Standard Time
W.Europe Standard Time
Central Europe Standard Time
Romance Standard Time
Central European Standard Time
W.Central Africa Standard Time
Namibia Standard Time
Jordan Standard Time
GTB Standard Time
Middle East Standard Time
Egypt Standard Time
Syria Standard Time
South Africa Standard Time
FLE Standard Time
Israel Standard Time
E.Europe Standard Time
Arabic Standard Time
Arab Standard Time
Russian Standard Time
E.Africa Standard Time
Iran Standard Time
Arabian Standard Time
Azerbaijan Standard Time
Mauritius Standard Time
Georgian Standard Time
Caucasus Standard Time
Afghanistan Standard Time
Ekaterinburg Standard Time
Pakistan Standard Time
West Asia Standard Time
India Standard Time
Sri Lanka Standard Time
Nepal Standard Time
Central Asia Standard Time
Bangladesh Standard Time
N.Central Asia Standard Time
Myanmar Standard Time
SE Asia Standard Time
North Asia Standard Time
China Standard Time
North Asia East Standard Time
Singapore Standard Time
W.Australia Standard Time
Taipei Standard Time
Ulaanbaatar Standard Time
Tokyo Standard Time
Korea Standard Time
Yakutsk Standard Time
Cen.Australia Standard Time
AUS Central Standard Time
E.Australia Standard Time
AUS Eastern Standard Time
West Pacific Standard Time
Tasmania Standard Time
Vladivostok Standard Time
Central Pacific Standard Time
New Zealand Standard Time
UTC+12
Fiji Standard Time
Kamchatka Standard Time
Tonga Standard Time
```

Comment: Thank You, one small thing please how can i point it out to use Philippine Time?

Comment: Have a look at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=netframework-4.8 it has a `ConvertTime` Method that can convert a datetime depending on a specified timezone.

Comment: I have edit my post including an exemple on how to convert datetime

Comment: Thank You SO SO MUCH <3